# How to self join and case when

Tags: mysql, join, case, self

I have this monster query from a java application that I am reverse engineering.

`

```
SELECT
    T.transferNumber,
    T.TransferNumber,
    T.BarrelsRequested - T.TotalBarrels br,
    TrTy.TransferTypeName,
    TrTa.SourceDest,
    Ta.TankName,
    SBP.SBPName,
    T.Notes
FROM
    RC.Transfers T,
    RC.TransferTypes TrTy,
    RC.TransferTank TrTa,
    RC.Tanks Ta,
    RC.ShipBargePipe SBP
WHERE
    T.TransferTypeNumber = TrTy.TransferTypeNumber
    AND T.TransferNumber = TrTa.TransferNumber
    AND TrTa.TankNumber = Ta.TankNumber
    AND T.SBPNumber = SBP.SBPNumber
    AND T.StartStamp IS NOT NULL
    AND T.EndStamp IS NULL
    AND T.Void IS NULL
    AND TrTy.TransferTypeName <> 'Truck'
UNION SELECT
    T.transferNumber,
    T.TransferNumber,
    T.BarrelsRequested - T.TotalBarrels,
    TrTy.TransferTypeName,
    TrTa.SourceDest,
    Ta.TankName,
    '',
    T.Notes
FROM
    RC.Transfers T,
    RC.TransferTypes TrTy,
    RC.TransferTank TrTa,
    RC.Tanks Ta
WHERE
    T.TransferTypeNumber = TrTy.TransferTypeNumber
    AND T.TransferNumber = TrTa.TransferNumber
    AND TrTa.TankNumber = Ta.TankNumber
    AND T.SBPNumber IS NULL
    AND T.StartStamp IS NOT NULL
    AND T.EndStamp IS NULL
    AND T.Void IS NULL
    AND TrTy.TransferTypeName <> 'Truck'
```

`

This returns a result set of:

[image]

But I really want:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.  As mentioned in the picture, I want rows that have the same transfer number to show up on one line.  I think I can achieve this using a self join, and
case when SourceDest = 's' AS 'FROM'
case when SourceDest = 'd' AS 'TO'

Also notice that when the type is Ship or Pipe, Then the from or To column becomes the SBPName depending on whether it is source or destination.

Thanks! Feel free to modify my question as you see fit too.

Edit*

Here is the java source code showing how they are grouping the rows together.
`

```
void updateRunning(Connection conn)
    throws SQLException
  {
    Query q = new Query(conn);
    this.jLabelRunningUpdate.setText("Reading");
    this.jLabelRunningUpdate.setVisible(true);

    q
      .setQuery("SELECT T.transferNumber, T.TransferNumber, T.BarrelsRequested - T.TotalBarrels br,       TrTy.TransferTypeName, TrTa.SourceDest, Ta.TankName, SBP.SBPName, T.Notes  FROM RC.Transfers T, RC.TransferTypes TrTy, RC.TransferTank TrTa, RC.Tanks Ta,       RC.ShipBargePipe SBP WHERE T.TransferTypeNumber = TrTy.TransferTypeNumber   AND T.TransferNumber = TrTa.TransferNumber   AND TrTa.TankNumber = Ta.TankNumber   AND T.SBPNumber = SBP.SBPNumber   AND T.StartStamp is not NULL   AND T.EndStamp is NULL   AND T.Void is NULL   AND TrTy.TransferTypeName <> 'Truck' UNION SELECT T.transferNumber, T.TransferNumber, T.BarrelsRequested - T.TotalBarrels,       TrTy.TransferTypeName, TrTa.SourceDest, Ta.TankName, '', T.Notes  FROM RC.Transfers T, RC.TransferTypes TrTy, RC.TransferTank TrTa, RC.Tanks Ta WHERE T.TransferTypeNumber = TrTy.TransferTypeNumber   AND T.TransferNumber = TrTa.TransferNumber   AND TrTa.TankNumber = Ta.TankNumber   AND T.SBPNumber is NULL   AND T.StartStamp is not NULL   AND T.EndStamp is NULL   AND T.Void is NULL   AND TrTy.TransferTypeName <> 'Truck'");

    ResultSetCA transfers = q.execute(false);

    this.jLabelRunningUpdate.setText("Updating");

    String sourceTankList = "";
    String destinationTankList = "";
    ResultSetCA runningList = new ResultSetCA();
    for (int count = 0; count < transfers.size(); count++)
    {
      sourceTankList = "";
      destinationTankList = "";

      String currentTNumber = transfers.getString(count, "transferNumber");
      while ((count < transfers.size()) && (
        currentTNumber.equals(transfers.getString(count, "transferNumber"))))
      {
        String sourceDest = transfers.getString(count, "sourceDest");
        String tankName = transfers.getString(count, "tankName");
        if (sourceDest.equals("s")) {
          sourceTankList = sourceTankList + tankName + ", ";
        } else {
          destinationTankList = destinationTankList + tankName + ", ";
        }
        count++;
      }
      if (!sourceTankList.equals("")) {
        sourceTankList = sourceTankList.substring(0, sourceTankList.length() - 2);
      }
      if (!destinationTankList.equals("")) {
        destinationTankList = 
          destinationTankList.substring(0, destinationTankList.length() - 2);
      }
      count--;int lastCount = count;

      String transferTypeName = transfers.getString(lastCount, "transferTypeName");
      if (!transferTypeName.equals("Tank"))
      {
        String sbpName = transfers.getString(lastCount, "sbpName");
        if (sourceTankList.equals("")) {
          sourceTankList = sbpName;
        } else {
          destinationTankList = sbpName;
        }
      }
      Number barrelsRemaining = transfers.getNumber(lastCount, "br");
      Object BBLS;
      Object BBLS;
      if (barrelsRemaining == null) {
        BBLS = "????";
      } else {
        BBLS = new Integer(barrelsRemaining.intValue());
      }
      Vector register = new Vector();

      Integer transferNumber = transfers.getInteger(lastCount, "transferNumber");
      String transferTName = transfers.getString(lastCount, "transferTypeName");
      String notes = transfers.getString(lastCount, "notes");

      register.add(transferNumber);
      register.add(transferNumber);
      register.add(BBLS);
      register.add(transferTName);
      register.add(sourceTankList);
      register.add(destinationTankList);
      register.add(notes);

      runningList.add(register);
    }
    Object key = null;
    if (this.jTableTransfersRunning.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
      key = this.jTableTransfersRunning.getSelectedKey();
    }
    this.jTableTransfersRunning.fill(runningList);
    if (runningList.size() > 0) {
      if (key != null) {
        this.jTableTransfersRunning.setSelectedKey(key);
      }
    }
    this.jLabelRunningUpdate.setVisible(false);
  }
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    T.transferNumber,
    T.BarrelsRequested - T.TotalBarrels AS `BBLs left`,
    TrTy.TransferTypeName AS `Type`,
    IF(TrTy.TransferTypeName = 'Tank',Ta.TankName,IFNULL(Ta.TankName,SBP.SBPName)) AS `From`,
    IF(TrTy.TransferTypeName = 'Tank',Ta1.TankName,IFNULL(Ta1.TankName,SBP.SBPName)) AS `To`,
    T.notes
FROM transfers T
JOIN transfertypes TrTy
    ON T.TransferTypeNumber = TrTy.TransferTypeNumber
LEFT JOIN transfertank TrTa
    ON T.TransferNumber = TrTa.TransferNumber
    AND TrTa.SourceDest = 's'
LEFT JOIN tanks Ta
    ON TrTa.TankNumber = Ta.TankNumber
LEFT JOIN transfertank TrTa1
    ON T.TransferNumber = TrTa1.TransferNumber
    AND TrTa1.SourceDest = 'd'
LEFT JOIN tanks Ta1
    ON TrTa1.TankNumber = Ta1.TankNumber
LEFT JOIN shipbargepipe SBP
    ON T.SBPNumber = SBP.SBPNumber
WHERE T.StartStamp IS NOT NULL
    AND T.EndStamp IS NULL
    AND T.Void IS NULL
    AND TrTy.TransferTypeName <> 'Truck'
ORDER BY TRANSFERNUMBER
```

Comment: That returns one line:

transferNubmer, BBLs left, Ship,  TransferTypeName,From,To,Notes

76252,108,Tank,Tank,null,Tank 051A,''

Comment: Which transfer number does it return (presuming it's from one of the rows in your question). What's the difference/significance between transferNumber and TransferNumber?

Comment: It returns the one tank to tank transfer. Which is 76252.
It's very strange how they are doing tank to tank, or tank to ship/barge, or barge/ship to tank.

Comment: Are they ever different?

Comment: Nope t.transferNubmer and t.TransferNumber is always the same.

If it's a ship, barge, or pipe transfer type, it seems as if there is only ever one row returned.  The from / to destination becomes the SBP (Ship Barge Pipe) name depending on whether it's a source or destination. And the other becomes the tank name.

if it is a tank to tank transfer there is always two rows returned, one for source tank, and one for destination. Why they designed it this way? Who knows. Seems like a ton of work to parse through this in code, versus just querying the database and displaying the results. :/

Comment: I've made an edit, but before reading your last comment. The bit about having only one row if not tank to tank is significant. It'll take a bit of head-scratching.... But run the updated query to see what the results look like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142772/discussion-between-sloan-thrasher-and-zack-scriven).

Answer (score 0):

Join with this subquery instead of joining with `TransferTank` directly:

```
(SELECT t1.TransferNumber, t1.TankNumber, t1.SBPName AS From, t2.SBPName AS To
 FROM TransferTank AS t1
 JOIN TransferTank AS t2 
    ON t1.TransferNumber = t2.TransferNumber
    AND t1.TankNumber = t2.TankNumber
 WHERE t1.SourceDest = 's'
 AND t2.SourceDesc = 'd') AS TrTa
```